# Resources for field data on BLE transfer speeds

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, arduino-nano

I'm currently working on a research project which revolves around me getting to know the transfer speeds of BLE in a simple setting. To be specific, I'll be working with an Arduino Nano 33 BLE board. I'm well aware that BLE v5 is capable of reaching speeds of up to 1Mb/s (Mega-bits/s) but is unrealistic in real-world applications. Are there any resources that I can get the transfer speeds of BLE? If not, I'm guessing I will have to work with an experimental setup for finding the speeds for my specific use-case. Thank you in advance!

Comment: [This guide](https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-5-speed-maximum-throughput/) from NovelBits was often shared in the past for this kind of questions. It could be that the Arduino Nano 33 is not capable of BLE 5 high throughput though. Implementing the standard is optional

Answer (score 0):

The Bluetooth Radio on the Arduino Nano 33 BLE is built into the NRF52840 MCU.

More information on the Radio is found here:
https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/topic/ps_nrf52840/radio.html?cp=4_0_0_5_19

There are definitely ways to determine real throughput of this peripheral, you just need a packet sniffer (link below) or have a transmitter/receiver board-to-board setup.

Packet Sniffer:
https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nRF-Sniffer-for-Bluetooth-LE

The board-to-board setup will have the relay serially send the number of packets received to a PC for analysis. You could configure the relay board to send the number of packets received within a certain interval (using the Timers in the NRF52840 with <microsecond precision).

If your project changes and you no longer need to use BLE and you would like to increase throughput to ~1.5Mbps, I developed and tested a working configuration of the NRF52840's Radio on the Arduino Nano 33 BLE. Link below.

https://forum.arduino.cc/t/stream-binary-data-from-arduino-nano-33-ble-to-pc-via-ble/917206